# webrtc not working after bundling the application

Tags: meteor, webrtc, meteorite, modulus.io

I am trying to implement [Simplewebrtc](http://simplewebrtc.com/) in meteor for video chat.
These are my files

```
#webrtc.html
<head>
  <title>meteorwebrtc</title>
</head>

<body>
 {{> navbar}}
 <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
  {{> video_chat}}
</div>
```

```
<template name="video_chat">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <video id="localVideo"></video>
    </div>
   <div class="col-md-8">
    <div id="remoteVideos"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
</template>

#webrtc.js

if (Meteor.isClient) {
  var webrtc = new SimpleWebRTC({

   localVideoEl: 'localVideo',

   remoteVideosEl: 'remoteVideos',

   autoRequestMedia: true
});
  webrtc.on('readyToCall', function () {

  webrtc.joinRoom('your awesome room name');
 });
}
```

and i include the simplewebrtc.js file inside lib directory so that i will be loaded first

```
lib/latest.js
```

video chat working fine when i try it in local and copy the code to server and run it but if i bundle and deploy the app using `meteor deploy meteor-webrtc.meteor.com` webrtc not working and it is not throwing any error. I even tried deploying the app in [modulus.io](http://modulus.io/) but there also i am getting the same result.

repo - [meteor-webrtc](https://github.com/rajanand02/meteor-webrtc)

Deployed app in meteor server - [meteor-webrtc.meteor.com](http://meteor-webrtc.meteor.com/)

How do i resolve this problem?

Comment: please post your webrtc code

Comment: I have the same error, I don't know why, in localhost its works.

Comment: issue resolved ? I'm curious as I am planning to implement webrtc with a meteor app, I am just not sure which js library to use. Any advise ?

Comment: @AwRak I managed to make it work..please refer this repo for example code  https://github.com/rajanand02/Gabble